# How to prevent Zend Framework 1 from resolving a controller name with a dot on its end?

Tags: zend-framework, url-validation

I have a website that runs on Zend Framework 1.12. It has a controller named 'users'. When I enter its name incorrectly — `http://mywebsite/userss` — I rightfully get an error saying that such controller does not exist. When I add a dot to the end of its name, however:
`http://mywebsite/users.`, an error says that a viewscript called `users./index.phtml` does not exist. Interesting thing is, it still gets the controller (users) correctly.

I have two questions regarding this matter:

1. How and why does it ignore a dot at the end, and still gets a controller correctly?
2. Is there a way to reject such controller names, without any modifications to the framework's core?

Answer (score 1):

Excellent question, but to answer this we have dig the source of Zend Framework and initially back To 2007, a function `_formatName()` was specially designed to remove such anomalies from the URL name. May be it was earlier than this but I don't know that.

This particular piece is from Zend Framework 0.1.4 (Historic Right??) :)

```
protected function _formatName($unformatted)
{
    $unformatted = str_replace(array('-', '_', '.'), ' ', strtolower($unformatted));
    $unformatted = preg_replace('[^a-z0-9 ]', '', $unformatted);
    return str_replace(' ', '', ucwords($unformatted));
}
```

Here you see `-`, `_`, and `.` removed on the very first step.

Even today, this function is set to remove `-` and `.` but not the `_`

Here is current Zend Framework 1.x version of that [function](https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/blob/master/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Abstract.php#L230)

```
protected function _formatName($unformatted, $isAction = false)
{
    // preserve directories
    if (!$isAction) {
        $segments = explode($this->getPathDelimiter(), $unformatted);
    } else {
        $segments = (array) $unformatted;
    }

    foreach ($segments as $key => $segment) {
        $segment = str_replace($this->getWordDelimiter(), ' ', strtolower($segment));
        $segment = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9 ]/', '', $segment);
        $segments[$key] = str_replace(' ', '', ucwords($segment));
    }

    return implode('_', $segments);
}
```

Just like before the URI Segment is clean out in this [line](https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/blob/master/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Abstract.php#L240)

```
$segment = str_replace($this->getWordDelimiter(), ' ', strtolower($segment));
```

The function `getWordDelimeter()` returns an array of `array('-', '.');`<sup>[[line]](https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/blob/master/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Abstract.php#L82)</sup> thus removing them first thing in the URL, which **answers your first question**. About the second question, you can modify [this](https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/blob/master/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Abstract.php#L82) line and remove the `.` from it.

```
protected $_wordDelimiter = array('-', '.');
```

After this the Despatcher will no longer find the controller or any URI component with `.` on it.